# How to display drupal 7 Ubercart product attribute options in views filter?

Tags: views, ubercart

I want to display drupal 7 Ubercart product attributes(for eg: size - Medium, Small, Large) as views filter in the products listing page. I have searched on google but did not find any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Add "add to cart form" field in view. we can see all attributes in view which are added for this product

Comment: Could you maybe add a screenshot for this? your solution sounds unorthodox.